# Converting SCX file to HTML

Tags: html, visual-foxpro

I am converting the Visual FoxPro(.scx) to plain html file.
I am not able to get the proper way to ready the (.scx) file.

I tried to convert the scx to html using the Visual Foxpro Foundation class, but it was not accurate.

Please someone help me identify the way for converting the Foxpro(.scx) to html.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create an HTML page that looks the same as the VFP form? Something else?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you may want to look at West Wind Webconnect. I believe there is a tool that connects VFP forms(.scx) to the web.

Comment: Forget it, You will finish it before if you make html from zero